# jQuery dialog before ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dialog

I have a form and a jQuery function which is triggered if user changes a html select field. The function collects all of the information what it needs and posts to a php script with an ajax post.
I want to extend this function with a new feature: if the selected value equals to a predefined value I want to display a dialog with two buttons. The user needs to click one of these buttons and if he does the new information will attached to the post.
An easy example:
The select has 3 options:
- Lemon
- Banana
- Apple

If the user selects lemon or banana, the scripts sends the info to the server without further actions. But if he selects apple, I need an extra dialog, because I want to ask if he needs a red or a green one. And it needs to be attached to the information which I want to send to the server.

Could you help me guys how should I do it?

I have only the first part:

```
$('select.myList').change( function()
{
    var e = $(this)
    var val = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id')

    var url = 'index.php?process'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { id: id, val: val },
        success: function(data){
            var o = $.parseJSON(data);
            if( o.error )
            {
                console.log('error:' + o.message);
            } else
            {
                console.log('success:' + o.message);
            }

            return false;
        }
        })

    return false
})
```

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: I have only the first part, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

First, I would say you should be extremely careful with your variable names. You should NEVER use `e` as a variable if it can be avoided. I would also change `id` and `val`.

In any case you should be able to use the `beforeSend` property in ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, so assuming that 'apple' would be the `val` of the element:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { id: id, val: val },
    beforeSend: function() { 
        if (val === 'Apple') { 
            //do stuff 
        }
    },
    // rest of ajax call 
}
```

Comment: Great, I haven't noticed beforeSend in the API. could you help me with the dialog too? :/

Comment: I guess I'll ask the obvious question - instead of trying to manipulate the data before send, is there a reason you couldn't add 'Apple - Green' and Apple - Red' to the select list? It feels a bit hokey to submit form on select change and then stop and ask for more info. Ultimately I think the solution I would suggest would be to modify the value to be one of those anyway, so why not just start with them if that's the info you need?

Comment: it was only a simple example, the real stuff is much more complex :)

Comment: I see - well I think the question still stands though, why not add the options to the select list initially, or expand the form to submit on click of a button and add a field that would display if a user selects apple? If you could set up a codepen with a real example that would be very helpful.